# CALayer not updating on window resize in macCatalyst

Tags: calayer, mac-catalyst

I've created a macCatalyst app, however when I resize the window, any CALayer sizes are not being updated.

For example:

```
extension UIView {

func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {

    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()

    let border = CALayer()
    border.name = "Top"
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    // Doesn't update
    border.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width:self.frame.size.width, height:width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}

}
```

The view resizes with the window resize using Autolayout, I also tried using the following, but still no joy on resizing the window.

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override var layer: CAGradientLayer {
        return super.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }
}
```